# How to add and remove the customised Chips from input

Tags: reactjs, typescript

only 2 days into React/typescript any help is much appreciate

**CC.chip** is the in-house customised Chip UI and can be used as
shown below.

```
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);
    const onClose = React.useCallback(() => {
        setIsOpen(false);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div >
            {isOpen && <CC.Chip text={tagString} size="m" onClose={onClose} dismissible />}
        </div>
    );
```

How can I add and remove an list of chips from text input, something like the figure shown below

[image]

The idea is create an array of strings to hold the chip tags. and create the tags(in form of chips) upon the tags array

So far this is what I have (shorten version without css):

```
export default function AddUserTag() {

    const [tags, addTags] = useState<string[]>([]);

    const handleKeyDown = (event: any) => {. // What's the proper type of event?
        if (event.key !== 'Enter') { return; }
        const inputValue = event.target.value.trim();
        if (!inputValue) { return; }
        addTags([...tags, inputValue]);
        console.log(tags);
        event.target.value = '';
    };

    return (
        <CC.FlexBox wrap alignItems="center">
            {tags.map((tag, index) => (
                <div key={index} >
                    {tag} // How to properly align the tag array and CC.chip(s)
                </div>
            ))
            }
            <CC.Divider orientation='vertical' invisible />
            <input onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} type="text" placeholder="Press enter to add tag" />
        </CC.FlexBox>
    );
}
```

Question 1:

what's the proper type of `event` in the function `handleKeyDown`? I was trying **KeyboardEvent** then  `event.target.value.trim();` and `event.target.value = '';` were
broken

Question 2:

How can I use the *CC.chips?* The *onClose* method on the chip doesn't return anything, I think pass the tag/string like this: onClose={() => onClose(tag)} shall remove the chip and the tag string in the array

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

```
import { KeyboardEvent } from 'react';

const eventHandler = useCallback((ev: KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {...}, [deps]);
```

Question 2:

If this is an internal component developed by you/your team/your company then we probably won't know how it works under the hood.

At first glance it looks like you should be able to listen pass a function to the Chip component and based on that you could remove tags from your `tags` state.

**Untested code**:

```
// Chip.tsx
const Chip: React.FC<Props> = ({ onCloseS }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);
    const onClose = React.useCallback(() => {
        setIsOpen(false);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div >
            {isOpen && <CC.Chip text={tagString} size="m" onClose={onCloseS} dismissible />}
        </div>
    );
}
```

```
// otherFile.tsx
const [tags, setTags] = useState<string[]>([]);

// tag: string but I'd keep tags as objects with unique IDs
const removeTag = useCallback((tag: string) => {
  const newTags = tags.filter((t) => t !== tag);

  setTags(newTags);
}, []);
```

But that'd require your Chip component's `onClose` method to return the tag value itself and I don't think it does based on your example.

If you could provide a small example somewhere then it'd be much easier to help you.

Comment: question1: I've tried KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement> but I got error `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.` for ` const inputValue = event.target.value.trim();` and  event.target.value = '';

Comment: There's a difference for `onChange` and `onKeyDown` event. `onKeyDown` event won't have `event.target.value` prop and that's correct. It only returns the key that's been pressed, not the whole input value. use `onChange` to get the whole input value.